# Matching column in CSV and exporting CSV with unique values

Tags: powershell

[image]

I am having two columns in a CSV: Client Name and Status.
For some clients, we have two Status as Failed and Success both. 
So, I want to filter those clients only which have status as only Failed.
Clients who are having two entries such as Failed and success also, I want to omit that.

I tried to apply `Where-Object`, but in it I am getting entries for clients whose status is a success also.

```
Get-Content "C:\Daily-Failed.csv" |
    Select-Object -Skip 10 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Failed"} |
    Select-Object "Client Name", "status" |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Failed-Only.csv"
```

Comment: please add a sample of your CSV file - the 1st few lines should be enuf. right now it is unclear if you have TWO rows for one client or you have both `Failed` and `Success` in the `Status` column of one row.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am having the same client name in two or more rows with Status sometimes as Failed and sometimes as a success, so I want to have a status which is only having value as Failed.

Comment: I have added Image in my Post for your reference. Please check

Comment: Textual information is preferred in textual form here on StackOverflow. The reason is that the people who are trying to help you will then not have to type the text in themselves, if they need it for their experiments or for explaining or demonstrating their solution. Putting that in text form is much less work for you and you can avoid answers which miss the point for some silly typo the answerer made while copying your text. So please [edit] your question to turn the picture of text into copyable text. This might help to do that https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process your imported CSV data (after the `ConvertFrom-Csv`) using the following steps:

1. Select the unique records from the input data (so that each client name has at most one "Success" and one "Failed" status associated with it).
2. Group the records by client name.
3. Select the groups that have a count of 1.
4. Expand the selected groups to retrieve the matching records.

```bsh
... |
    Select-Object -Unique * |
    Group-Object 'Client Name' |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 } |
    Select-Object -Expand Group
```

If your data also contains records where a client name has only a status "Success" associated with it, you need to adjust the `Where-Object` filter to remove those records from the result:

```bsh
... |
    Select-Object -Unique * |
    Group-Object 'Client Name' |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 -and $_.Group.Status -eq 'Failed' } |
    Select-Object -Expand Group
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, your code work great with little modification.
Select-Object -Unique * | Sort-Object 'Worflow Start Time' -Uniq  | Group-Object -Property 'Client Name','Save Set Name','Group','Worflow Start Time' | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 -and $_.Group.Status -eq 'Failed' } |Select-Object -Expand Group

Comment: yes I will but I am facing one issue in it, if the same client backup is successful in one group and failed in another group then also it will not show me as it got the backup as successful for that particular client. so I want that it considers the group also while showing the report. can u please help in here

Comment: @GURUSINGH That is a followup question, and you need to provide more information for that. Please create a [mcve] and post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
$csv=Get-Content "C:\Daily-Failed.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 10 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$CSVWithoutFailed= ($csv | where status -ne 'Failed')."Client Name"
$csv| where "Client Name" -notin $CSVWithoutFailed | select -Unique *
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. It worked fine for me. I did slightly change in code as an addition to the client, It have save sets column also like C:\, D:\ Drive. So in place of Client Name I put Save Set name and it worked fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: I was just thinking that is there any way to do it in Shell scripting. Please help

Comment: Why use shell, PowerShell core work on linux now ^^

Comment: Bro. your code is working fine but when there are multiple save sets for one client and all those are failed, it gives me only one or two save set.I am using the below code.$csv=Get-Content $Location"Daily-Failed.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 10 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$CSVWithoutFailed= ($csv | where status -ne 'Failed')."Save Set Name"
$csv| where "Save Set Name" -notin $CSVWithoutFailed | Select-Object "Client Name", "Save Set Name", "status", "Group" | Export-Csv  -NoTypeInformation $Location"Failed.csv"

Comment: Input is :                                                                                                                        
 Client Name,Save Set,Status
Star,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Sun,D:/,Failed
Star,C:/,Success
Sun,D:/,Success

Comment: Desired output is :                                                                                                             "Client Name","Save Set",Status
Galaxy,D:/,Failed
Moon,C:/,Failed
Star,D:/,Failed

Answer (score 0):

this is a slightly different way to get the job done. [*grin*] it presumes the double entries will *never* have two `Failure` items.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
Client_Name, Status
Alfa, Failed
Alfa, Success
Bravo, Success
Charlie, Failed
Delta, Success
Delta, Failed
Echo, Failed
Foxtrot, Success
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Results = $InStuff |
    Group-Object -Property Client_Name |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Count -eq 1 -and
        $_.Group.Status -eq 'Failed'
        } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group
        }

$Results
```

output ...

```
Client_Name Status
----------- ------
Charlie     Failed
Echo        Failed
```

at that point, you can neatly export to a CSV file with Export-CSV.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in shell scripting

Comment: @GURUSINGH - i don't understand your question ... would you please try to reword it?

Comment: Sir, I would like to achieve the same thing using .sh script

Comment: i do not know any of that ... i am responding to your _powershell_ tag. if you do NOT want powershell code, then you should remove the powershell tag & replace your powershell code with your `.SH` code - and perhaps add a tag for that since `shell` is far too generic.